# How to hide the button from a non-user and non-admin?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";

if(empty($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == '0')
{
echo "<p><a href='view.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Admin 
button</a></p>";
}
?>
```

This is my button code↑

It can only hide the button from user, and will display as error to a non-registered user, what should i do?

PS: 0 means admin, 1 means user

Comment: String `'0'` is considered __empty__ in php. You have to redesign your roles so as not to encounter such problems any longer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";

    if(
         isset($_SESSION['role']) 
      && ($_SESSION['role'] == '0' || $_SESSION['role'] == '1')
    {
    echo "<p><a href='view.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Admin 
    button</a></p>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: this code makes the button appeared when logged in as user

Answer (score -1):

Use isset instead of empty.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include "connection.php";

 if(isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == '0')
 {
   echo "<p><a href='view.php' 
            class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Admin 
    button</a></p>";
 }
?>
```